# Which method will be faster and safer to cache json data?

Tags: android, json, caching, sharedpreferences

I should make an application which will work on offline mode and online mode. I will cache Json data which comes on online mode then the user will become able to use this app on offline mode.

I am using **jackson library** to get json from an url. I must cache **JsonNodes** to the device. Users will not be able to see that cached data. I am now using **SharedPreferences** method on Private mode. The code is working perfectly. No overloading and no slowdown.

I want your ideas to make a perfectly working safe application. Is **SharedPreferences** the right method to cache data? If not, why? Again if not, what problems i will face when i used SharedPreferences?

Comment: you could use a network library that works with cache, to make it transparent.

Comment: (I think Volley does such things)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using SharedPreferences for caching. SharedPreferences is meant to store, well, _preferences_, and small structures, not big amounts of cached data. You can use `Context.getCacheDir()` for that. The difference being that the cache directory can be cleared by the used when it grows too large, SharedPreferences can't. In addition, SharedPreferences may be backed up to Google's cloud (if the user chose to enable it), which isn't desired in the cached data case.

Comment: I can clear my SharedPreferences, and i can control the size of cached data programatically.